# Unexpected behavior of the AIC.svyglm function (R survey package version 4.1-1)

Tags: r

I have a search algorithm that uses the R survey package function `AIC.svyglm` on linear regression models. I updated the package to version 4.1-1 and have some issues with the new function.

I noticed in the help page that, in the new version, "`extractAIC` for a model with a Gaussian link uses the actual AIC based on maximum likelihood estimation of the variance parameter as well as the regression parameters" while it used to use the Rao-Scott approximation so I don't expect to obtain the same results. However, I noticed an unexpected behavior.

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(survey)
data(api)

# Define a simple design, for illustration
dclus2<-svydesign(id=~0, weights=~pw, data=apiclus2)

# 3 models (note: Gaussian family)
model0<-svyglm(I(sch.wide=="Yes")~ell+meals+mobility, 
              design=dclus2, family=gaussian())
model1<-update(model0, formula = .~.+as.numeric(stype), 
              design=dclus2, family=gaussian())
model2<-update(model0, formula = .~.+stype, 
              design=dclus2, family=gaussian())

# 'Equivalent' lm
model0lm<-lm(I(sch.wide=="Yes")~ell+meals+mobility, data=apiclus2, weights=pw)
model1lm<-update(model0lm, formula = .~.+as.numeric(stype))
model2lm<-update(model0lm, formula = .~.+stype)

summary(model1)
summary(model1lm)

#AIC on svyglm
AIC(model0,model1, model2)

#AIC on lm
AIC(model0lm,model1lm, model2lm)
```

The results are, for the svyglm:

```
         eff.p      AIC deltabar
[1,]  8.686176 803.6719 2.171544
[2,] 14.317939 811.0289 2.863588
[3,] 30.163107 746.8759 5.027185
```

while we do expect the AIC from model 1 to be lower than the one for model 0. For the `stats` lm

```
         df      AIC
model0lm  5 198.6607
model1lm  6 166.9859
model2lm  7 131.5015
```

Do I miss something?

I use R version 4.1.0 and survey version 4.1-1

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading the AIC value directly from the svyglm models just like this:

```
c(model0$aic, model1$aic, model2$aic)
#[1] 198.6607 166.9859 131.5015
```

Note that this way you get exactly the same values as from the `AIC` function applied to the lm models.

```
AIC(model0lm,model1lm, model2lm)
#          df      AIC
# model0lm  5 198.6607
# model1lm  6 166.9859
# model2lm  7 131.5015
```

I realize this does not answer the question of why this differs from the results from `AIC(model0, model1, model2)`.
Perhaps, however, this will be the solution to your problem.